# How can I get a div with multiple classes using querySelector()

Tags: javascript, css, screen-scraping

I want to an element based on the class applied to it. For example

```
<div class="a_class">contents</div>
```

I can get this by using simple querySelector like

```
document.querySelector("div.a_class")
```

Now, I want to get an element based on multiple classes, for example:

```
<div class="a_class b_class">content of class a and b</div>.
```

Comment: `div.a_class.b_class`

Comment: try this document.querySelectorAll('.class1.class2');

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

document.getElementsByClassName('class1 class2')

I found it from here:

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/selecting+multiple+classes+js